# Installation (5.69.1) fails: Server 500 Error (Joomla 5.02)

Tags: joomla, installation

I just wanted to update from an older version (I gues it was 5.63 or so) to the current 5.69.1, but the installation runs into a red screen with a Server 500 error.

This is what I see after turning on debugging and trying to launch CiviCRM:
https://i.imgur.com/CuFfNbd.jpg

Any idea, what I can do?

My Joomla is 5.02, PHP is 8.1.27

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Hi Stefan
Return to the URL **[DOMAIN]/administrator/index.php**
Navigate to **components/civicrm**. 
In the main menu of CiviCRM navigate to **Administer > Administration Console > System status**. 
There you should find an error message with a link to execute the necessary database-upgrade. Once executed/finished successfully, the error no longer shows up.
Alternatively, you can execute the upgrade directly via the link **[DOMAIN]/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1**.

Comment: Thank you for the tip!
Unfortunately, I can't login any more, because I instantly get this screen: https://i.imgur.com/eUJnI05.jpg no matter which URL I try to open! :-(

Comment: Any help how can can log into my backend again is very much appreciated?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply: navigate to the database via phpMyAdmin and find the table #_extensions of your joomla-installation. Deactivate extension-entries CiviCRM, CiviCRM User Management, CiviCRM System Listener by setting enabled = 0. Then you should be able to perform a backend-login.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for reaching out.
I found a table 'jos_extensions' but in that no CiviCRM entries. Am I looking at the wrong place?

Comment: For whatever reason I can log in to my backend again. Uninstalling CiiCRM still fails. Reinstalling I don't dare, I don't want to be locked out of my system again.
And - unfortunately - the support here is quite poor, so I wouldn't want to take the risk again.
Any hints how I can proceed are still welcome.

Comment: You could delete the entries com_civicrm, the plugins civicrm, civicrmsys and civicrmicon from the #_extensions table. Additionally, delete all the tables with prefix civicrm_ Delete the folders administrator/components/com_civicrm, components/com_civicrm and media/civicrm via server control panel or FTP. Like this, you "manually" uninstalled CiviCRM and a new/reinstallation should be possible.