# HELP needed: Joomla backend no longer accessible after CiviCRM installation!

Tags: joomla, error

after trying to update CiviCRM on my Joomla 5.02, first I got some errors when launching CiviCRM, now I cannot login my Backend as admin at all.
(see related question: [Installation (5.69.1) fails: Server 500 Error (Joomla 5.02)](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/46206/installation-5-69-1-fails-server-500-error-joomla-5-02))

This is what I'm seeing when I try to login as admin: https://i.imgur.com/CuFfNbd.jpg

Any help is welcome, because I can't do ANYTHING right now!!

Stefan

Comment: Is your civicrm.settings.php file missing? It seems like your include_path isn't getting set up.

Comment: where would I find such a file?
I don't even find a folder that looks like civicrm, neither in /components nor administrator/components

Sorry, I looked on the wrong server 
adminitrator/components/com_civicrm/script.civicrm.php is there.

Comment: I managed to get back into the backend (renamed /plugins/civicrm.php)

When trying to install civicrm again I get this error message: https://i.imgur.com/UwSeDy1.jpg

Comment: Double post: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/46206/installation-5-69-1-fails-server-500-error-joomla-5-02